# Ansible find and delete JDK folders

Tags: ansible, find

we have path and different folders inside

```
adobe_tools_path: "/apps/cq5/tools/"
```

is it possible to delete only *JDK pattern folders via loop?

my playbook is not matching JDK folders as a pattern

```
- name: Find JDK folders
  find:
    paths: "{{ adobe_tools_path }}"
    patterns: "*jdk"
  register: wildcard_folders_to_delete

- name: Remove file JDK wildcard
  file:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    state: absent
  loop: "{{ wildcard_folders_to_delete.files |flatten(levels=1) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `recurse`:

```
  - name: Find JDK folders
    find:
      paths: "{{ adobe_tools_path }}"
      patterns:  "*jdk"
      file_type: directory
      recurse:   yes
    register:  jdk_folders_to_delete

  - name:  Remove unneeded JDK folders
    file:
      dest:  "{{ item.path }}"
      state: absent
    loop:  "{{ jdk_folders_to_delete.files }}"
```

Comment: loop is mandatory due to asible version ((

Comment: It might help if you shared the version so it can be reviewed - Ansible 2.7.6 does not have that requirement.

Comment: we're using 2.5.2 but as far as I know, all items stuff should be rewritten to loops in all our cases. don;t ask why ))

Comment: The likely reason is someone read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50456997/ansible-with-items-vs-loop and `loop` may be preferred in some shops.  However, I think your issue may be not using `recurse: yes` in the `find` module.  See updated answer.